# check first dataframe value startswith any of the second dataframe value

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two pyspark dataframe as follow :

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(
    ["yes","no","yes23", "no3", "35yes", """41no["maybe"]"""],
    "string"
).toDF("location")

df2 = spark.createDataFrame(
    ["yes","no"],
    "string"
).toDF("location")
```

i want to check if values in **location** col from **df1**, **startsWith**, values in **location** col of **df2** and vice versa.

Something like :

```
df1.select("location").startsWith(df2.location)
```

Following is the output i am expecting here:

```
+-------------+
|     location|
+-------------+
|          yes|
|           no|
|        yes23|
|          no3|
+-------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using spark SQL looks the easiest to me:

```
df1.createOrReplaceTempView('df1')
df2.createOrReplaceTempView('df2')
joined = spark.sql("""
    select df1.*
    from df1
    join df2
    on df1.location rlike '^' || df2.location
""")
```